# Why does my page content repeat?

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have a content type I created called News. The pathauto pattern is "news/node title".

I created a view page to list all the News. The path to the view page is "news".

When I go to the view page, all the articles are listed.

When I click on one article, I get "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" errors, the view page is shown twice. The third repeat of the content shows the article. The full template, header and footer and everything is repeated for all three.

I tried renaming the view's path to "foo" but then I get file not found errors on all my "news/node title" pages.

I tried renaming my pathauto pattern to "content/node title" and the view to "news" and both the view and the news pages work.

Why can I not use "news" for the path to my view and "news/node title" for the path to the articles?

Comment: Does your view use any arguments (called contextual filters in D7)?

Comment: maybe it's because that machine name is already in use...not sure though

Comment: No there are no contextual filters. It's a really simple view. The machine name isn't in use, but perhaps when I changed the page name of my view it didn't delete it from the database? There's a lot of cruft leftover whenever you delete things and it's very hard to find where it lingers.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention I'm using drupal 7. I've named my taxonomy vocabulary "news-categories" so that should not be an issue. This news section is the only part of the site I have built so far. I can't seem to get past it.

Comment: Wow, it does not work for node/7 URLs either. Same repeating content.